# How to fix email template responsive probelm with grid layout when test it in mail

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, email-templates

I am creating an HTML Email template. There I have a section with 3 column. I am not facing any problem when I run it my local machine but when I send it as mail I am having trouble of responsive or anything else that I can understand.

1. First I use **SASS** & compiler to compile it to **CSS**.
2. Make another **HTML file & take compiled CSS code**.
3. In   tag I set the CSS code as **(Internal CSS)**.
4. It show as like as I want in my **Local Machine. Large & Small device perfectly**. Like

https://ibb.co/T89v0fB

5. When I test it with (**Puts Mail**) site and send mail. In laptop it show errors although the mail body is larger than 500px/600px. The error is my 3 column show in 1 row. Like:

https://ibb.co/8mRXC5d

6. Here is my code in code pen, with HTML & SASS

https://codepen.io/mrhrifat/pen/xxgBQZd?editors=1100

7. Here is my code, with HTML & CSS (Same code like above but it is in Internal CSS style. And the CSS code compiled from SASS)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rating</title>
    <style>
        /*===== 05) Global CSS Section =====*/
        .btn,
        .container .latest .row .col1 .card-footer button,
        .container .latest .row .col2 .card-footer button,
        .container .latest .row .col3 .card-footer button {
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: red;
            padding: 15px 30px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            line-height: 120%;
        }

        .btn a,
        .container .latest .row .col1 .card-footer button a,
        .container .latest .row .col2 .card-footer button a,
        .container .latest .row .col3 .card-footer button a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 140%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /*===== 06) Container Section =====*/
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 650px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /*===== 08) Latest Section =====*/
        }

        .container .latest .row {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: -ms-grid;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-areas: 'sec1 sec2 sec3';
            -ms-grid-columns: auto auto auto;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col1 {
            padding: 5px;
            -ms-grid-row: 1;
            -ms-grid-column: 1;
            grid-area: sec1;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col1 .card-body small {
            display: block;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 10px 10px 0;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col1 .card-body p {
            padding: 10px 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            color: green;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col1 .card-body span {
            border-top: 2px solid black;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            display: block;
            width: 20%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col1 .card-footer button {
            padding: 12px 22px;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col2 {
            padding: 5px;
            -ms-grid-row: 1;
            -ms-grid-column: 2;
            grid-area: sec2;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col2 .card-body small {
            display: block;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 10px 10px 0;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col2 .card-body p {
            padding: 10px 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            color: green;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col2 .card-body span {
            border-top: 2px solid black;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            display: block;
            width: 20%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col2 .card-footer button {
            padding: 12px 22px;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col3 {
            padding: 5px;
            -ms-grid-row: 1;
            -ms-grid-column: 3;
            grid-area: sec3;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col3 .card-body small {
            display: block;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 10px 10px 0;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col3 .card-body p {
            padding: 10px 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin: 0;
            color: green;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col3 .card-body span {
            border-top: 2px solid black;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            display: block;
            width: 20%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .container .latest .row .col3 .card-footer button {
            padding: 12px 22px;
        }

        /*===== 15) Media Query Section =====*/
        @media screen and (max-width: 365px) {
            .latest .row {
                grid-template-areas: 'sec1''sec2''sec3' !important;
            }
        }

        /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
    </style>


</head>

<body>

    <!-- Container Section Start -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Latest Section Start -->
        <section class="latest">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <small>Rating</small>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of typesetting industry.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button>
                                <a href="#">Download Now</a>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col2">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <small>Rating</small>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of typesetting industry.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button>
                                <a href="#">Download Now</a>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <small>Rating</small>
                            <p>
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of typesetting industry.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button>
                                <a href="#">Download Now</a>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Latest Section End -->

    </div>
    <!-- Container Section End -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to what the email services supports.

A list of restrictions can be found at the following link:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/